# NumbersOnly property of TEdit control

Tags: c++builder, vcl

It is not clear from [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.NumbersOnly) whether the `NumbersOnly` property set to "true" allows introducing numbers with the decimal separator. In my small test, I came to the conclusion that only integer numbers are allowed, but I am not sure about that, and am looking for a confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NumbersOnly` property sets/clears the [`ES_NUMBER` style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/edit-control-styles) on the Edit's HWND handle:

> **Allows only digits** to be entered into the edit control. Note that, even with this set, it is still possible to paste non-digits into the edit control.

So no, it does not allow the user to *type* a decimal separator, but the user can *copy/paste* one into the edit field.

If you want the user to be able to *type* a decimal separator, do not set `NumbersOnly` to true, use the `OnKey(Down|Up|Press)` events instead to filter out unwanted keystrokes manually as needed.

Otherwise, find a 3rd party Edit control that natively supports decimal number input. Many popular VCL component suites (TMS, DevExpress, etc) have custom Edit controls with more features than what the standard `TEdit` provides.